# how to extract index (multiple-level) for dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'dts':['1/1/2000','1/1/2000','1/1/2000','1/2/2000', '1/3/2000', '1/3/2000'],
                            'product':['A', 'B', 'A','A', 'A','B'],
                            'value':[1,2,2,3,6,1]})
a =mydf.groupby(['dts','product']).sum()
```

so a has multi-level index now...

```
a
Out[1]: 
                  value
dts      product       
1/1/2000 A            3
         B            2
1/2/2000 A            3
1/3/2000 A            6
         B            1
```

how to extract product-level index in a? a.index['product']does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [**`get_level_values`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html)

```
>>> a.index.get_level_values(1)
Index(['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'], dtype='object', name='product')
```

You can also use the name of the level:

```
>>> a.index.get_level_values('product')
Index(['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'], dtype='object', name='product')
```

Comment: And `a.index.levels[1]` to get just index categories.

Comment: I find some related solution by using reset_index. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html